# Connect GraphQLModule in NestJs

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I've read official [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start) , and I'm doing the same, but have an error in typescript generic, how can I fix it?

[image]

Dependencies :

```
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.11.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "@tatumio/tatum": "^1.28.7",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.25.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1015.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
```

Comment: are you using `@nestjs/graphql` v10.0.2 (the latest)?

Comment: updated body of a question with dependencies

Comment: looks like `@nestjs/graphql` v7 doesn't has that generic. v10 does